# Problem with naming and display name of picture in frame, <a> in HTML

Tags: html, css

I try to create my portfolio with using GitHub Pages https://rageanalyst.github.io/Portfolio/. I use a template and alter him. I don't know HTML. I have a problem with caption when I open a frame with project. Two pictures don't underneath, they have (untitled). Only the last picture have caption and is the project tittle.

Problem: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyOJL.png)

Q: How can I add caption to individual pictures in this frame?

This is extract of code when I have a single project:

```
<article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
   <a href="images/thumbs/trainings.JPG" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/fulls/gym.jpg" alt="" />
   <a href="images/thumbs/dchart.jpg" class="image fit"></a>
   <a href="images/thumbs/weical.JPG" class="image fit"></a>
   </a>
 <h3>Gym Tracker</h3>
 <p>This project contains tables that allow me to track my progress in the gym. </p><br>
 <ul class="actions">
 <li><a href="https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=9DFECE4104674424%21106&ithint=file%2Cxlsx" class="button">Full Project</a></li>
 </ul>
</article>
```

Edit:
I still haven't solved the problem, anyone else can help me?

Comment: First of all there is an HTML error. Your first `<a>` is closed last before the `<h3>` headline. Put the `</a>` after the image, so same line as the first `<a>`.

Comment: OK, and what's next?

Comment: It seems the caption comes from the `<h3>` within the `article` tag. So you would have to create a `article` for every image and the `h3` will be its caption. Maybe there is a workaround by giving the image a `title` attribute have you tried that? That is specific to GitHub pages, maybe check out their help?

Comment: Adding another <article> creating another project, so in this way i have another frame.
Yes, I tried add title and it doesn't work.